# MySQL Docker container does not execute startup script

Tags: mysql, docker

We are studying a docker-compose system of microservice containers https://github.com/networknt/light-docker
We have been deploying it for some time on our server with the MySQL as a database (https://github.com/M3SOulu/light-docker), but at some point, the deployment started breaking and other services could not access the database anymore.

After manually inspecting the container, I noticed that the initializaing `.sql` script is not executed on container startup (so the necessary database is not there for other containers), even if all images/containers are deleted and the deployment is done from scratch.

The script is put into into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and is found there after manually accessing the container (see part of `docker-compose.yml` below).

```
  version: '2'
  services:
    mysqldb:
      image: mysql:5.7.16
      ports:
        - 3306:3306
      volumes:
        - ./light-oauth2/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      networks:
        - localnet
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlpw
```

The two explanations I found seem to be

- There are wrong permissions on the file.

This does not seem to be the case since we did not modify file permissions of the `.sql` file and it worked before; also the file can be given to MySQL by root user without any problems inside the container. Also, I tried doing `chmod a+r` on the `.sql` script and it did not fix the problem.

- Scripts in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` do not get executed if there is already data stored in the data folder.

We do not mount the data folder outside the container, so re-building the container should always start with empty data folder, and as I mentioned in the beggining, even doing `docker system prune -a` does not solve the problem, the container still does not load the script.

What could be the source of the problem here? It is weird to me that things worked well initially, but at some point doing `docker compose up` started producing this problem.